# How to fix the call_user_func_array error in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am receiving the following error. How do I fix it?

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "wp_initialize_theme_preview_hooks" not found or invalid function name in /home/trickit/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 Stack trace: #0 /home/trickit/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 /home/trickit/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 /home/trickit/public_html/wp-settings.php(506): do_action('plugins_loaded') #3 /home/trickit/public_html/wp-config.php(97): require_once('/home/trickit/p...') #4 /home/trickit/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/trickit/p...') #5 /home/trickit/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/trickit/p...') #6 /home/trickit/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/trickit/p...') #7 {main} thrown in /home/trickit/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Comment: i have a suggest for you


Add your code plus what you want to do to get a faster and better answer to your question.